# phpQuery displaying special text

Tags: php, phpquery

I am using phpQuery for extracting data from a url. Now when i extract data from a url i get some improper or special characters in place of text.

```
Like:  ctype html&gt; ,   ¢Â�Â�
```

My script:-

```
PhpQueryComponent::newDocumentFileHTML($file,$charset='utf-8');
```

My output is:-

```
 ctype html&gt; It's as if we created some text and blah just for you, the small business owner
or self-employed carpenter, gardener, caretaker, artist or shop owner who needs all the 
help you can get. On Sfsfsdfe, you can create your own website so your clients can   
find you. Display all your products in photo albums, describe your services or 
experience, and put up news and special events to create buzz around your business.      
¢Â�Â� the list is endless, and so are the tasks linked to running them. With fdsfsdf
albums Ã¢Â�Â� there's a function for your every need. Communicate directly on the page 
and keep each other up to date.
```

I have useutf-8 , but still its not working properly. Can anyone tell me why is this error being displayed.??
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

you might have special characters in the file you are reading ,`so this is happening as All HTML special characters might be broken up when parsed via phpQuery.`

**this is an issue with phpQuery,** [issue](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/issues/detail?id=176)

---

**update:**
you said 'you have used UTF-8' , had you have used like this? .. if not then do the following..

firstly save your file in UTF-8 format and check the meta part,it should be:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

also set php header `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the begining.

Comment: Is there any way to overcome this ??

Comment: i have updated my answer, try setting `meta and header` in php , then tell me what you are getting..

Comment: I am getting the same text, no improvement wat so ever